# DBCC on SSAS Cube fails

Tags: ssas, dbcc, cube

DBCC on the Cube fails(SQL version 2014 SP2, 12.0.5000.0).
My XMLA query:
[image]

Error message:
Executing the query ...
The DBCC element at line 7, column 88 (namespace https://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2016/engine) cannot appear under Envelope/Body/Execute/Command.
Run complete

I can find anything wrong with a query.Tried 2003 and 2014. According to books online, it should just work:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/database-consistency-checker-dbcc-for-analysis-services?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read the rest of the docs?

> Output when running DBCC against an earlier version of Analysis
>   Services
>
> DBCC is only supported on databases running on a SQL Server 2017
>   instance. Running the command on older systems will return this error.

```
Executing the query ...  
The DBCC element at line 7, column 87 (namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine) cannot appear under Envelope/Body/Execute/Command.  
Execution complete
```

**Updated**
Here is a link that explains things a bit more in detail than the docs you're are referencing.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4077/consistency-checks-for-sql-server-analysis-services/

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Mötz! No way to do the DBCC check against the Cube in SQL 2014 then, so may move it to a newer version.

Comment: Wrong info from MS - DBCC on SSAS is supported starting from SQL 2016.

Comment: Could you either share a blogpost or similar source of information to support that?